# Замкнуть [замыкания]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить и синонимизировать идентичные метки:

- [замыкание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (8 вопросов)
- [замыкания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (18 вопросов)

Вопрос - какую метку сделать главной?

Comment: Предлагаю удалить их.

Comment: Обычно множественное число выбираем.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да ладно, метка вроде бы осмысленная. Успеем удалить, если окажется бесполезной.

Comment: Давайте добавим ещё туда же [tag:closure]

Answer (score 0):

Мне в данном случае больше нравится единственное число: [замыкание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Скорее всего, из-за того, что замыкание обычно одно, а вопрос, связанный с взаимодействием замыканий придумывается с трудом.

Comment: Вопрос может быть не о конкретном замыкании, а о замыканиях вообще: как работают, как использовать, и т.п.

Comment: Вот шикарный вопрос: [Каррирование в JavaScript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488120/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: @NickVolynkin значит ли это, что надо обе метки иметь? Еще бы по [другим](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4665/176217) разобраться.